# LESS - Using a variable on a CSS class

Tags: less

This is a bit of a long shot, but I wondered if its possible to set a `number` as part of `class` and based on that number use it to set the `height` of the `CSS`

HTML Example:

```
<div class="div-height-100"></div>
```

LESS Basic idea:

```
.div-height-@var{
    height: @height;
}
```

CSS Output:

```
.div-height-100 {
    height: 100px;
}
```

The idea of this is due to having multiple empty-chart-loader DIVs all of which are different heights, and will save setting up a different CSS class for each height.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do like this `.div-height-@{var}{height: unit(@var,px);}`. If you have multiple such classes/heights, you can use ar array list variable and loops to generate multiple classes also.

Comment: You may wish to take a walk through [the documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-selectors). Though in this particular case the idea of hardcoding an element size/position into a CSS class name is usually considered to be vastly flawed. (If you have to have something like that it's achievable with `<div style="height: 100px"></div>` w/o any CSS).

Comment: Thanks guys, the class is being set on a HTML Helper, which I can't use in-line styling on. I have been using jquery `data` attributes recently and thought I could do something similar here, as I'm relatively new using Less I'm still getting used to it's capabilities and best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LESS is compiled into CSS so its values, after be processed, can't be modified by classes defined in HTML code.

In order to obtain a result similar to one that you're trying to obtain, you must create different CSS classes in advance.

```
.div-height-100 {
  height: 100px;
}
.div-height-200 {
  height: 200px;
}
.div-height-300 {
  height: 300px;
}
.div-height-400 {
  height: 400px;
}
```

This CSS can be automatically generated using the following LESS code, that use [LOOPS](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) construct (note also use of [EXTRACT](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract) function). I'm assuming that you already know what are possible "height" values, and stored them in a LIST. You can simply add more values to list, in order to generate more CSS classes:

```
//Possible height values
.div-heights(100, 200, 300, 400);

.generate-heights-loop(@var; @possible-values) when (@var <= length(@possible-values)) 
{
  //Let's extract values in @var position from list @possible-values
  @height: extract(@possible-values, @var);

  .div-height-@{height} 
  {
    height: unit(@height,px);
  }

  .generate-heights-loop((@var + 1), @possible-values);
}

.div-heights(@possible-values...) 
{
  .generate-heights-loop(1, @possible-values);
}
```