# Generate variables with loops ("Shorter/friendly-named alias for a complex statement" problem)

Tags: loops, less

I know that in LESS is possible to generate many CSS classes using [loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature). I personally used this technique to answer another [user's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068010/less-using-a-variable-on-a-css-class/28153993#28153993).

Now I'm facing the following code:

```
@transparent-black-10: fade(@nero, 0.1);
@transparent-black-20: fade(@nero, 0.2);
@transparent-black-30: fade(@nero, 0.3);
@transparent-black-40: fade(@nero, 0.4);
@transparent-black-50: fade(@nero, 0.5);
@transparent-black-60: fade(@nero, 0.6);
@transparent-black-70: fade(@nero, 0.7);
@transparent-black-80: fade(@nero, 0.8);
@transparent-black-90: fade(@nero, 0.9);

@transparent-white-10: fade(@bianco, 0.1);
@transparent-white-20: fade(@bianco, 0.2);
@transparent-white-30: fade(@bianco, 0.3);
@transparent-white-40: fade(@bianco, 0.4);
@transparent-white-50: fade(@bianco, 0.5);
@transparent-white-60: fade(@bianco, 0.6);
@transparent-white-70: fade(@bianco, 0.7);
@transparent-white-80: fade(@bianco, 0.8);
@transparent-white-90: fade(@bianco, 0.9);
```

I'm wondering if is possible to generate also LESS variables like above, using Loops, or this is denied by language. If possible, do you have some suggestion to generate above code more efficiently?

Comment: At-least, generating the suffix in the variables would be very tough (almost impossible).

Comment: @Harry: I'm sorry, I am not sure to have correctly understood. Are you saying that is impossible to generate this with a loop? I could only compact variable name using [variable name](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names) feature?

Comment: There's no way to "generate" variables dynamically (And I guess it will never be). If I understand your goal correctly, in a conventional language this use-case is normally solved via functions, e.g. instead of creating a banch of variables (which is hmm ... strange to say at least) one would just define `transparent-white(value)` function. But Less has no functions functionality too so you have to either keep things as-is or to rethink it from scratch.

Comment: (well, it's hard to suggest anything w/o knowing more details of your use-case... In a simple case why just do not define `@white: @bianco;` and use `fade(@white, 0.9);` instead? After all there's no semantic difference between `fade(@white, 0.9);` and `@transparent-white-90`).

Comment: @LucaDetomi: Sorry for being unclear, was typing the comment from phone so kept it too short. Yes, I felt this was almost impossible on the whole and that at the very least the generation of suffix numbers (10, 20 etc) in the variables would be tough.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: thank you for your answer. I know that this example could seem "strange". Effectively I don't currently need a bunch of variables like this, but I discovered a very similar list in a CSS framework and their "likeness" inducted me to ask myself if "could be possible to generate it automatically with LESS". This is the reason for my question, more theorical than pratical. In some cases could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Now when Less v3.x and higher provides native support for custom functions).

Just as in most of other programming language, instead of a list of auto-generated/predefined variables, this programming problem is solved via `function` functionality.
I.e. you define a function like:

```
.transparent-black(@value) {
    return: fade(@nero, @value ./ 10);
}
```

And then instead of `@transparent-black-*` variable you simply use `.transparent-black(*)[]` function call, e.g.:

```
div {
    color: .transparent-black(50)[];
}
```

This is obviously a simplified example (in a real project I certainly would make `black/white/etc` to be the function parameters too).

Comment: Thank you but it seems that correct function should be `return: fade(@black, @value);`, because in case of `color: .transparent-black(50)[];`, with your code results `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);` Am I wrong?