# LESS: Generate dark or light variation of a color set based upon a parameter

Tags: less

Some days ago I made a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079094/less-generate-variables-with-loops)  in order to generate LESS variables with a `LOOP`.

Today I start from the same topic with a similar topic. I have the following colorizer theme:

```
// Colors
@color-gray:                rgb(225,225,225);
@color-black:               rgb(15,15,15);
@color-blue:                rgb(37,117,237);
@color-red:                 rgb(222,44,59);
@color-yellow:              rgb(255,200,0);
@color-green:               rgb(44,159,66);
@color-white:               rgb(255,255,255);

// Colors Dark
@color-gray-dark:           rgb(179,182,183);
@color-black-dark:          rgb(0,0,0);
@color-blue-dark:           rgb(26,82,165);
@color-red-dark:            rgb(178,35,47);
@color-yellow-dark:         rgb(204,160,0);
@color-green-dark:          rgb(35,127,53);

// Colors Light
@color-gray-light:          rgb(240,240,240);
@color-black-light:         rgb(55,55,55);
@color-blue-light:          rgb(146,186,246);
@color-red-light:           rgb(239,150,157);
@color-yellow-light:        rgb(255,228,128);
@color-green-light:         rgb(150,207,161);
```

*Seven-phases-max* already answered me:

> There's no way to "generate" variables dynamically

So, how to optimize creation of a similar colorizer? If could be possible to generate variables, ideal behaviour should pass a "dark" or "light" parameter to a function that loops through each "standard" color variation and then generates dark or light version automatically.

Some suggestion about it?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure I understand the question. Is it "how to generate these derived color values" or is it "what are possible methods of referring to such automatically generated colors w/o generating global variables"?

Comment: @seven-phases-max: in another question you already said me that is not possible to generate variables so now my question is "generally" what could be the better solution to obtain a final behaviour similar to one achieved by this long set ov variables? I was thinking, but it's only an idea, about a mixin (maybe with a lopp if necessary) to which I pass an a set of color variables (i.e. the first group in my code) and then a parameter that assign dark/light variation to each one. In this way, changing a theme would be obtained toggling a single parameter.Or maybe do you have better suggestions?

Comment: I see. I'm afraid there's no currently. Though if you don't mind "not-so-standard" Less (e.g. involving non-core functions of plugins), the best *real* one I can imagine is something [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/785466e826f428734c80) probably (a simplified minimalistic example to illustrate the very idea). But honestly it's not something I would suggest to use (too tricky and verbose). I can imagine a much more clean way (finally making use of real Less functions I mentioned earlier, but this will require another plugin that is not ready for production yet).

Comment: I'll wait for future development. I also hope that LESS changelog will become more self-explained because often happens that I am not able to understand what are new features, that maybe could be also very useful. An inspiration could be Firefox developer notes, that lists them in details.
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but not long ago I had to face a similar issue and solved it by using LESS mixins as functions, and based on a main color (e.g. background color), deciding which variant to use (light or dark).

E.g.

```
@mainColor: #F4F8F8;

.generate(@color) when (lightness(@color) >= 50%) {
    // 'Color variables here'
}

.generate(@color) when (lightness(@color) < 50%) {
    // 'Color variables here'
}


.generate(@mainColor);
```

Not sure if it meets what you are looking for.

Cheers.