# Simpler way to achieve CssLess interpolation

Tags: css, less

I'm doing some interpolation of variables with Less CSS (I think thats the correct term), however I can't help but think I've got more steps than I need.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
@blue50:#e3f2fd; // concrete colorways
@green50:#e8f5e9;
@red50:#ffebee;
```

... and I set the current theme like this:

```
@primaryColor:'blue';
```

... and have some helper stuff which helps me retrieve the correct color:

```
@primary50:@@_primary50; // It feels like these 2 lines should be 1!
@_primary50:'@{appPrimaryColor}50';
```

This enables me to refer to `@primary50`, which in turn returns the correct blue color (@blue50) based on the theme I've set.

As you can see there are 2 helper steps, which I think could be simplified. However, I've been unable to work out the correct syntax to make this work. It seems like a trivial measure, but there are over a hundred colors and several themes, so it is a bit of a longwinded approach.

The first step, would be to simply the number of steps.

Secondly, if possible, I would like to produce a loop that could take care of all hues in the color. In my example I use the 50 hue, but the full range consists of 50,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900, so that @blue50, @blue100, blue200 etc.

/* EXAMPLE OUTPUT */

Swatches for 'blue'

```
@blue50:#e3f2fd;
@blue100:#bbdefb;
@blue200:#90caf9;
@blue300:#64b5f6;
@blue400:#42a5f5;
@blue500:#2196f3;
@blue600:#1e88e5;
@blue700:#1976d2;
@blue800:#1565c0;
@blue900:#0d47a1;
```

Set the theme:

```
@appPrimaryColor:'blue';
```

Use these helper variables for each hue

```
@primary50:@@_primary50;
@_primary50:'@{appPrimaryColor}50';
```

And access colors using these variables

```
@primary50:@@_primary50;
@primary100:@@_primary100;
@primary200:@@_primary200;
@primary300:@@_primary300;
@primary400:@@_primary400;
@primary500:@@_primary500;
@primary600:@@_primary600;
@primary700:@@_primary700;
@primary800:@@_primary800;
@primary900:@@_primary900;
```

And use it stylesheets

```
.mystyle1 {
    color:@primary50;
}
.mystyle2 {
    color:@primary100;
}
```

Comment: The first part of the question is simple to handle but this bit is not possible because you can't form variable names dynamically- *In my example I use the 50 hue, but the full range consists of 50,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900, so that ...*. But depending on how the output CSS should be, maybe loops can be used. If you show your expected CSS output, I can suggest a way.

Comment: Looks like an "XY Problem". Could you provide more details of what you need these variable for?

Comment: @Harry - it's not easy to provide a great example as it is simply a transition  based on temporary variables, but I've added an example of how I might use it.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - I'm creating a site template based on Google's material design. There are 22 color palettes, each of which has 10 color hues - each has a naming convention of 'color + hue', so blue50, blue100 etc. I want to be able to set the color, 'blue' and let Less calculate the values. These can then be accessed throughout the css as '@primary50' or '@primary100', which will allow me to change the theme in one place without referencing the entire stylesheets.

Comment: @JohnOhara: In that case, would it not be easy to do something like [this](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40blue50%3A%23e3f2fd%3B%20%2F%2F%20concrete%20colorways%5Cn%40green50%3A%23e8f5e9%3B%5Cn%40red50%3A%23ffebee%3B%5Cn%40blue100%3A%20blue%3B%20%2F%2F%20concrete%20colorways%5Cn%40green100%3Agreen%3B%5Cn%40red100%3Ared%3B%5Cn%40primary50%3A%20~%5C%22%40%7B%40%7BappPrimaryColor%7D%40%7Bhue%7D%7D%5C%22%3B%5Cna%7B%5Cn%20%20color%3A%20%40primary50%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%40appPrimaryColor%3A'blue'%3B%5Cn%40hue%3A%2050%3B%22%7D) instead of dynamically forming variable names?

Comment: Thanks for the example Harry. The only issue I have is that although 'primary' is mapped to a single color, hue refers to one of the 10 hues - so primary50 can only refer to hue 50 (resulting in blue50) and  primary100 would only refer to hue 100 (blue100).

Comment: So you mean you would need colors of different hues within the same CSS file? Can you give me one sample (just pseudo-code) so that I can see if there is a way to achieve it?

Comment: @Harry - I've added more code in the example - if you need anything else please shout

Comment: I suppose than it's basically the same use case as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079094/less-generate-variables-with-loops. Note that you cannot define variable with a name defined by another variable. Instead you should really consider a classical design-patterns like generic list/array, namespaces and custom functions (e.g. using `less-plugin-functions`). Not via global constant variables (i.e. in simplest case generating `@foo-50`-like variables to be used instead of `foo(50)` is [just odd](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2702#issuecomment-144826702)).

Comment: To not sound unfound here's basic "namespace" [example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9f48fa5d71edf6e8cb59) (w/o any Less plugins needed) - still using that ugly predefined global constants stuff but at least not requiring the bloody `~"@{foo@{bar@{baz}}}"` syntax.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - thanks for your help

Comment: @seven-phases-max - I've taken a look at your example, and unfortunately I don't think its going to work for me. The issue is that it won't support multiple themes in its current guise. For instance a site will have a minimum of a primary and accent palette.

Comment: "a minimum of a primary and accent palette" - this does not really change the approach [too much](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/5c2b59aba9ecc681437c). Though I'd still suggest to use custom functions in a long run (that's what I would use no matter what (at least because it's about `number-of-semantic-color-ids * number-of-colors-per-shade` times less code to write), and yet again there's no reason for `@primary100` to be better than `primary(100)`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - thanks for your updated answer. It works for me. I'm interested in your second approach too, but I'm not sure how the custom function would work in this context - are you referring to a mixin? Sorry Less isn't my forte.

Comment: By custom functions I mean really just "custom functions" (either defined with in a custom JavaScript plugin or directly in Less using [`less-plugin-functions`](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-functions#less-plugin-functions)). Briefly the implementation and usage might look [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/566ec789a36d60a1bc31) (the snippet doesn't take into account any optimizations, specific `A` colors, additional namespacing for clean names etc. etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see there are 2 helper steps, which I think could be simplified.

To answer this particular question, a one-liner equivalent for:

```
@primary50: @@_primary50;
@_primary50: '@{appPrimaryColor}50';
```

(assuming the value *is a color*) could be written as:

```
@primary50: color("@{@{appPrimaryColor}50}");
```

But since there're too many reasons to not use such code, as well as counting that the whole snippet itself is more like an XY-Problem, it would be worth to *consider alternative implementation approaches* for the use-case (certain tips and examples are mentioned in the question comments, though it's just too many affecting factors and too many specific patterns to put everything into a single answer).